# Can't compile after switching from Xcode 6 beta 2 to beta 3

Tags: xcode6, beta

I have no idea why, but once I switched to Xcode beta 3, I can't get anything in my project to compile. This is what I'm seeing all over the build log...

:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254`

This helped:
[Xcode 6 beta 3: invalid virtual filesystem overlay file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622650)

Comment: Have you re-installed the Command Line Tools ? Xcode has that annoying feature of not storing old install states when you upgrade...

Comment: Yes, I've reinstalled the command line tools as well as deleted derived data and cleaned the project... This linked gave me a little more info on what is going on though...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622650