# XCode 6 Beta 3 gives many compilation errors

Tags: ios, xcode

The recent release of Xcode6 Beta 3 is giving lot of compilation errors, specially with cocoapods. There is a a temporary fix in this link: [Xcode 6 beta 3: invalid virtual filesystem overlay file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622650/xcode-6-beta-3-invalid-virtual-filesystem-overlay-file)

But this fix does not work if you are depending on AFNetworking or other pods as in my case.
I went back to Beta 2, till a more stable solution will be available.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: If anybody should know how to fix problems in beta releases, it must be the authors of that beta release. Please report this to Apple (your non-disclosure agreement prohibits you from discussing this outside of their forums anyway :-)

Comment: Try rebooting computer

Comment: tried all those superstitious things, but didn't help.