# Xcode fails to autocomplete for libraries imported via cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

For the last two days, Xcode has been acting very strangely.  I can build and run my app, but autocomplete does not work for anything I've imported via cocoapods or subclasses created from those libraries.  I also get (real) errors if I don't include certain libraries explicitly under Scheme -> Build.  Previously I believe I only had to include `Pods` there.

When I start typing, Xcode starts throwing up all sorts of red markers, and it thinks all imported types are `int *`.  Sometimes autocomplete continues to work for, e.g. NSString, sometimes not.  But actually building still works.

I've tried reinstalling cocoapods (now v 1.1.1), deintegrating cocoapods, and modifying my header search paths (currently `"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/"`).  Also, deleting `DerivedData`, restarting computer, Xcode, etc...

I have a sneaking suspicion that this is related to mixing Swift and Objective C in my project.  As I've used swift more and more, most of the time when I build I need to delete and recreate `all-product-headers.yaml` ([See thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622651/467209)).  I don't have any firm evidence that this is related, though.

Errors when I type.  `UserProfile` is an `RLMObject` subclass.

[image: Errors when I type]

Scheme Settings.  Realm, Masonry, and AFNetworking are already included in `Pods-iLingQ` but build fails without including them first as well.  These do happen to be the three libraries I use most extensively in my app.

[image: Scheme settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by my adding a new target without creating that target in my Podfile.  For some reason I was able to build and work in that target *most* of the time, but not always.  Adding the the target, doing `pod install` and then cleaning allowed me to build and use autocomplete again.